# CodeBlocks can't insert brackets

Tags: c++, codeblocks, shortcut, brackets

When I use CodeBlocks, for C++ and I try to insert brackets, I use <kbd>ALT-GR</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>ALT-GR</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.
B for left and N for right. Now in CodeBlocks, when I insert B, which is left, it appears like this and doesn't insert a bracket:

```
/** \brief 
 *
 * \return void
 *
 */
```

I couldn't find the right answer anywhere, so I'm posting here.

Comment: Check the keyboard bindings in your settings.

Comment: I tried and I can't seem to find a command :(

Comment: fixed :) I just had to disable plugin for Keyboard Shortcuts! :)

Comment: @user1907457: You need to either close this or supply your own answer and check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either disable the DoxyBlocks-plugin (if you don't need it) from "Plugins -> Manage plugins", or chose another shortcut for "DoxyBlocks -> Block comment" from "Settings -> Editor -> Keyboard shortcuts".